# transform unique values using pandas groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, defaultdict

I have input dictionary like:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "objType": "master",
            "objName": "sampleOne",
            "objTitle": "Sample One"
        },
        {
            "objType": "master",
            "objName": "sampleTwo",
            "objTitle": "Sample Two"
        },

    ]
}
```

and I want to group the same values of key `objType` to generate the dict as below

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "objType": "master",
            "objDetails": [
            {
                "objName": "sampleOne",
                "ObjectTitle": "Sample One"

            },
            {
                "objName": "sampleTwo",
                "ObjectTitle": "Sample Two"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I have used pandas groupby but not able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure pandas is appropriate for what you want to accomplish, given the multi=tiered structure o your data.  The following function will correctly parse your data, base on your example input and desired output.

```
def transform(di):
    tmp = dict()
    for ntry in di['objects']:
        tval = tmp.pop(ntry['objType'], [])
        indict = dict()
        indict['objName'] = ntry['objName']
        indict['ObjectTitle'] = ntry['objTitle']
        tval.append(indict)
        tmp[ntry['objType']] = tval
    return {'objects': tmp}
```

Given input of

```
di = {
    "objects": [
        {
            "objType": "master",
            "objName": "sampleOne",
            "objTitle": "Sample One"
        },
        {
            "objType": "master",
            "objName": "sampleTwo",
            "objTitle": "Sample Two"
        }
    ]
}  

transform(di)
```

produces:

```
{'objects': 
           {'master': [{'objName': 'sampleOne', 'ObjectTitle': 'Sample One'},
                       {'objName': 'sampleTwo', 'ObjectTitle': 'Sample Two'}]}}
```